# What kind of artificial intelligence jobs are out there?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, data-mining

Throughout my academic years in computer science I fell in love with many aspects of artificial intelligence. From expert systems, neural networks, to data mining (classification). I wonder, if I was to transform this academic passion professionally, what kind of AI-related jobs are out there?

Comment: This may not be a job so much as an oppourtunity, but someone should take ALICE and turn that into a "live chat" help desk. www.alicebot.org

Comment: Note that data-mining is much more than just classification. Classification is more of a machine learning / AI subject than "pure" data-mining (which is a lot about integrated data management and analysis). These two domains are surprisingly separate in the research community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would be surprised at the number of domains where AI-based approaches are used. From optimal industrial control, process management and optimization, to business rules and financial modeling, to text analysis, machine translation, search engines...

Almost anywhere humans have been used to take complex decisions based on data, the amount of data modern electronic communications and acquisitions methods produce has become too much to handle without software. And only "intelligent" (or at least, less single-mindedly stupid) software can handle the complexity of the data, the complexity of the rules, and the numerous failure modes.

Answer (score 6):

Professor for Artificial Intelligence courses. ;)

Comment: What are your students going to do with their skills, teach more?

Answer (score 6):

The most obvious answer to me are games.

I think games present a very interesting challenge for AI, because you're essentially [playing to lose](http://www.gamedev.net/columns/events/gdc2008/article.asp?id=1344) but [in a fun way](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3947/intelligent_mistakes_how_to_.php).

Comment: i find the chosen answer is much better

Comment: What you call *AI* in games most often has nothing to do with the scientific field of *AI*.

Answer (score 2):

I know one software company in my city is using AI, that was developed as a Masters in Engineering project, to detect fraudulent bank/financial transactions.  It's pretty interesting stuff.  They look for strange recurring payments, or compare account numbers based on known terrorist organizations ...etc.  I'm not sure how many people are doing similar work, but i'm sure with the lock-down on financial institutions these days these types of applications will become more prevalent (it's working for them).

Comment: Yes, there is a major financial company that had an intrusion. They now use ai for fraud detection. Several others are using it as it "just works better"

Comment: Funny enough, i now work at the company that i mentioned above and get to see how the AI stuff works.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from direct application - AI people also are usually hardcore algorithms people by nature, and that kind of knowledge is sought after everywhere.